# BsonDateTimeOptions with DateTime?

Tags: c#, mongodb

i came through a problem with mongodb via c#,

when i try to save an object to mongodb i get this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'A serializer of type 'StringSerializer' is 
not configurable using an attribute of type 'BsonDateTimeOptionsAttribute'.'
```

this is the property that cause the problem :

```
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Unspecified)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

The problem is with the fact that it's a null-able DateTime property,

what can i do in order to make the Serialize work properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So i have found the problem, the problem wasn't with StartDate field, it was with another filed of type string that i didn't noticed that i marked as BsonDateTimeOptions, so the Bson serializer tried to serialize a string as a DateTime.